# Anidar namespace en un solo alias

Tags: php, php8, namespace

Existe alguna forma no documentada de anidar/consolidar espacios de nombres:

```
use Qa1\{
    Class1,
    Class2,
} as AliasQa1;
```

Esto da error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "as", expecting ";" in
> test.php on line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente hasta la version de php 8.2 y las anteriores, no se admite una sintaxis de importacion multiple a un solo/mismo Alias la forma correcta seria:

```
use Qa1\{
    Class1 as AliasQaCl1,
    Class2 as AliasQaCl2,
};
```